# Python Assignment Expressions syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.9, I've a function that returns a `tuple[float, float]` as follows:

```
return slope := _slope(c1, c2), _y_intercept(c1, slope)
```

I use the assignment expression as defined in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

But it gives me the following error:

```
test_moderate.py:None (test_moderate.py)
../../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:578: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.fspath, mode=importmode)
../../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:524: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1030: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
../../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:170: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
test_moderate.py:4: in <module>
    from moderate import functions as func
E     File "/moderate/functions.py", line 346
E       return slope := _slope(c1, c2), _y_intercept(c1, slope)
E                    ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
collected 0 items / 1 error
```

Comment: If you are `return`ing on that line, then the assignment surely serves no purpose. Just `return` the expression.

Comment: Anyway, you haven't asked a question, and your implied question is answered [in the link you gave](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases): "Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited as annotations for arguments, return values and assignments."

Comment: Probably need to add parentheses

Comment: Reason I didn't add parentheses is because PyCharm shows a warning about "redundant parentheses", but it does make the error go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap that expression in `()`:

```
return (slope := _slope(c1, c2), _y_intercept(c1, slope))
```

I'm guessing your code was being parsed as something like:

```
return slope (:= _slope(c1, c2), _y_intercept(c1, slope))
```

Which doesn't make sense. When in doubt, throw some parenthesis around the expression and see if that changes the behavior. If it did, it's likely a precedence issue.

---

I'll admit though, I'm not sure why that's necessary. I would expect `return` to fully allow the expression on its right to evaluate before it executes. `:=` does have the lowest precedence of any operator, but I would still expect it to evaluate before `return`.

Looking over the [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), it might have to do with the fact that `return` is defined as taking the form:

```
return_stmt:
    | 'return' [star_expressions]

star_expressions:
    | star_expression (',' star_expression )+ [','] 
    | star_expression ',' 
    | star_expression

star_expression:
    | '*' bitwise_or 
    | expression
```

And `:=` introduces a `named_expression`, not an `star_expressions`:

```
named_expression:
    | NAME ':=' ~ expression 
    | expression !':='
```

meaning it's incompatible. Wrapping the named expression in parenthesis turns it into a `star_expressions`, which is allowed in that context. Or at least that's my guess. I'm not very experienced with reading grammar specifications.

Comment: Reason I didn't add parentheses is because PyCharm shows a warning about "redundant parentheses", but it does make the error go away.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Unfortunately, there's a few bad warnings that Pycharm gives. It's a great tool, but it's not perfect.

Comment: FWIW, putting `# noinspection PyRedundantParentheses` on the method suppresses the warnings. Another option is to add inline `#noqa`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar That may silence the warning, but I think this is a bug that should be fixed. This is either a "bug" in the grammar specification (unlikely), or in Pycharm's linter (more likely since this is kind of an odd corner case). If I have time at some point, I might report this to Jetbrains. You could as well if you have an opportunity.

Comment: I can't think of why `:=` would cause issues in this context though, besides the fact that it seems like poor practice and a bit nonsensical (I'm assuming you were reassigning a global?). It seems like it could be "fixed" by just defining a new rule as something like `return_expression: | named_expression | star_expressions`, then doing `return_stmt: | 'return' [return_expression]`. This might seem like such a useless case though that it isn't worth the change.